# Как получить верхний уровень объекта в Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, объекты, get

Есть объект, нужно по значению получить его верхний уровень

```
   level1 : {
       level2: {
         ...
          { 
            levelN: {
              key: value
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Найти top по `value`

```
search( obj, value) // top
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы найти самый верхний уровень:

```js
const obj = {
  1: { 2: { 3: 'hello' } },
  10: { 20: { 30: { 40: 'world' } } }
};

function getKeyByValue(o, value) {
  let node, ch = Object.entries(o);
  while (ch.length > 0) {
    node = ch.pop();
    if (node[1] === value) {
      return node[0];
    }

    if (node[1]) {
      const e = Object.entries(node[1]);
      for (let i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        ch.push([node[0], e[i][1]]);
      }
    }
  }
  return 'Not found';
}

console.log(getKeyByValue(obj, 'world'));
```